# Get postal code by entering Landmark

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox, in which user will enter a Landmark and I have to retrieve a postal code of that landmark. I have no idea how to complete this task. I need some assisstance

Comment: Did you find the service that gives such information?

Comment: No, is there a database of postal code of the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your best bet. Use Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup) on Google Map API to retrieve the postal code

> > The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse,
> >     translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is
> >     known as reverse geocoding.
>
> The Geocoding API supports reverse geocoding directly using the latlng
>   parameter. For example, the following query contains the
>   latitude/longitude value for a location in Brooklyn:
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
>
> This query returns the following result:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "275-291",
      "short_name": "275-291",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "short_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Kings",
      "short_name": "Kings",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "11211",
      "short_name": "11211",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
```

Read more : [**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types)

Comment: At least that's what's written there. I have never tried though. So instead of asking me, why don't you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Would you possibly be able to use the Google Maps API? I know you can search a landmark name and return coordinates, but I'm not sure if you could then lookup the coordinates to retrieve a postcode?

Comment: I got Latitude and Longitude of a landmark using google API, but my requirement is still to get postal code. Is there any I can get postal code by Longitude and Latitude?