# get all postal codes within 15 miles by postal code

Tags: vb.net

I need a zip code radius finder and calculator in my asp.net application where i will provide a zip code, a distance (in miles) and should get a list of zip codes which are the specified miles away from the specified zip code

Answer (score 3):

See these posts:

[Get postal code by entering Landmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295718/get-postal-code-by-entering-landmark)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316940/get-all-postal-codes-within-15-miles

Also, this article is very thorough:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32806/GeoLocation-by-Radius-Using-Google-Maps-and-NET